# Naming someone "eternal" in Islam?

Tags: naming

I am sure every Muslim believes that Allah(SWT) is the only eternal supreme Being. Given that, I have heard, from Muslim scholars, that it's not appropriate to give children names that might show similarity to the attributes of Allah.

That said, **Khalid**, a popular Arabic name(Khalid Ibn Al-Waleed: A companion of the Prophet(PBUH)), which means *immortal or eternal*, seems to be widespread across the Islamic world. I wonder if the ***properly-Islamic-naming*** principle applies to this name.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is ok, for if there were a problem the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon Him) would have said something, for there are many instances where the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon Him changed a persons name, for example [this case](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/182).  Furthermore the rule in naming is that one chooses a good name.

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we suggest you take a look at the [FAQ](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq).  Here we require answers to contain citations/references, and we discourage one line answers.  I have edited your answer to make to expand on your original, I hope I have not changed it too much, you may wish to edit it to add or subtract something.

Comment: barak allah fiik